# Are 2D graphics bottlenecked on modern 3D GPUs by the pipeline, making them significantly slower to draw relative to 3D models?

Tags: graphics, 3d, 2d

I'm making a 2D game currently and one of the supposed experts in the community claims that 2D sprites require more instructions than a 3D model, and thus they will render at the same speed.

Coming from a university computer science bachelor degree background and not knowing the true current state of modern GPUs, this doesn't make sense to me, since even if a 2D image can't skip some of the pre-rasterization process, and is treated as a 3D object, it's still a simpler object to process than a 3D one.

Wondering if anyone can explain in depth, as I can't find any evidence online supporting this, nor is he willing to provide any.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general, you are right in that 2D scene consists of sprites should consume less processing power and memory than, let's say a 3D scene with very complex objects and lightings.

My guess would be that the experts you mentioned are saying that 2D scene may require more GPU power in pixel shader stage since sprites are rectangles that may contain large transparent portion which still consumes pixel shading (see the below image). in contrast, for opaque 3D objects, only visible portion will be processed by pixel shaders in most cases.

[image]